# The Rites of Protection?

Tags: mantras, shloka, stotra

Are there any Mantra, Stotra, shloka for protecting oneself, from internal and external foes.

Comment: I found this [article](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1717&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) and couldn't get the source of Mantra written.. can anyone write it in Sanskrit instead of english.

Comment: I thought you are generally asking about protecion mantras etc.. the link you gave contains info about how a Sri Vidya initiate ought to protect oneself during the process of their Sadhana. That is not provided so that they can be  generally used by everyone. For general protection you can chant the Stotras I gave. That article is relevant only for Sri Vidya initiates of a particular Sampradaya.

Comment: @Rickross I was generally asking too.. please post your answer again..

Comment: Ok I have now undeleted my answer. I actually did not open the link before answering. I just saw the question and posted the answer. If a link is very relevant to the question then you can put it in the question's body instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: @Rickross .Thanks as always.. The link was not-much relevant to the question, that is why I didn't write it in the question body.. Im trying to collect all rites related to protection..

Answer (score 5):

The Sanskrit word ["Raksha" means "protection"](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=rakSA&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3).

So, the Stotras which immediately come to mind are the [Shiva Raksha Stotra](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shiva_raksha_stotram) by Rishi Yajnvalkya and the [Rama Raksha Stotra](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Rama_Raksha_Stotram) by Budha Kaushika.
The Stotras are so called because if chanted they protect the aspirant in every way.

Both these are like protective armours (Kavacha Stotra).

Quoting from the Shiva Raksha Stotra's Phalasruti:

> Yetham shiva balo petham., raksam ya sukruthee padeth,
>  Sa bhukthwa
> sakalan kaamaan, shiva sayujyamapnuyath,
>  Graha bhootha
> pisachadhya, trilokyepi charanthi ye,
>  Dhoorad aasu palayanthe
> Shiva namabhi rakshanath., 9
>
> That blessed one who reads this protection, Which is blessed with
> power of Lord Shiva, Would get all his desires fulfilled, Attain
> nearness to Lord Shiva after death, And planets, ghosts and ghouls,
> Which travel in any of the three worlds, Would run immediately, far,
> far away, Due to the protection given by names of Shiva.
>
> Abhayam kara namedham kavacham Parvathi pathe,
>  Bhakthya bibarthee
> ya kande, thasya vasyam jagat thrayam,
>  Imam Narayana swapne Shiva
> Raksham yadha disath,
>  Prathar uthaya yogeendro, Yagna valya
> sthadha likath., 10
>
> This armour of the names of the consort of Parvathi, Would remove
> fears and provide protection, To the devotees who sing these often,
> And the lord of the three worlds would be within his hold, For this
> protection of Lord Shiva was revealed, By Lord Vishnu in the dream to
> Yagna Valkya, Who wrote it, as he was told, as soon as he woke up in
> the morning.

Answer (score 5):

Durga Saptshati provides **Durga Kavach mantra** for one's safety. Detailed shloka in English with meaning is provided here [Durga Kavach with English translation - Durga Saptshati](http://astro121.com/index.php/durga-ma-devi-kavacha-english).

I'd share the shlokas in Sanskrit with their summary, taken from [Durga Saptashati by Gita Press - Kindle version](https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B07B1TKSRG/). Durga Kavach was told to Markandeya muni by Brahma ji as one of the most secret mantra. At first he describes Navdurga or nine forms of Durga. He talks about other forms of Devi and their rides (Vaahan) as well.

> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]
> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]

Brahma ji asserts that all these Devis are very angry, holding various weapons like Trishul, Chakra etc. They are ever ready to help the devotees while destroying evil. Keeping this in mind, the actual kavach mantra starts.

First various Devis are prayed to protect our body from all directions. These are both absolute (north, south etc.) and relative (left, behind etc).

> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]
> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]

It is followed by praying for security of each part of the body, starting from face. We request Devi to protect our forehead, eyes, ears mouth etc. It's important to note that we pray for both outer and inner body parts. We pray for securing our heart, chest, kidneys, stomach, reproductive organs. Then we pray for our legs : knee, sole of feet, toes and nails. We also pray for blood, muscles, bones, even body pores.

> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]
> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]

Having secured our body, we move to saving our character. We pray for our pride, mind, even shadow. We pray to safeguard our five senses, trigun (sattva, rajas and tamas) and long life. We pray for our fame, name, wealth, wisdom and dharma.

Then we pray for our family : children, wife and our ancestors. We pray for our animals, our paths and anything and everything we mentioned or forgot to.

> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]
> [image: Durga Kavach - Durga Saptshati]

It is asserted that if we recite this before going anywhere, no harm will come to us. All wishes would be granted, we'd receive wealth and become fearless. No disease or sickness will come to us, and that our name and fame will last forever.

Comment: thank you for very detailed answer, really good

Comment: please share the link to added screenshots. please\

Comment: @HinduKid screenshots taken from Durga Saptashati kindle version https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B07B1TKSRG/

Comment: please join this chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133400/durga-kavacha