# Mantras for protection against evil beings

Tags: mantras, tantra, agamas

Could anyone tell me which Sanskrit texts (Agama/tantra Shashtras in particular) contain mantras for protection against (and/or to control) evil beings and influences?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/the-rites-of-protection/49310#49310 this may be helpful